# Why do I have fewer settings (policies) in my GPO editor in my domain compared to another domain?

Tags: active-directory, policy, gpo

As I wrote in the title : Why do I have fewer settings (policies) in my GPO editor (domain 1 in the screenshot) in my domain compared to another domain?

Any idea please? I have already applied admx patch, windows update .. Etc

Domain 1 :

[image: Domain 1]

Domain 2 :
[image]

Edit: still need help please

Comment: any idea please :'( ?